# How to tell if a string relating to a file exists, but also more specifically, is local

Tags: php, file

I have a file path stored in a string.  This could be a local file path, or anything else (think HTTP/FTP as well).  file_exists() works well for checking this but it also returns true if the file exists and is on the FTP protocol, I only want to know if the file is specifically local to the machine (as far as is reasonable).  I don't want to do a regex check or anything for protocol as there are more protocols than just HTTP and FTP that are in use here and so it's not feasible to try and exclude all of these.

Comment: Why don't you want to make a protocol check? `://` is not a (partial) valid name on any filesystem you will be using in practice, and if you find it it's dead easy to determine if the protocol is "file" or not (you don't really care what it is if it is not "file"). If you *don't* find `://` then obviously it's a local file path. Simple to implement and will work for everything you will encounter in practice.

Comment: @AndreasLinden: I have already mentioned that possibility: if you find a protocol and it is "file", strip the protocol and continue.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, the file:// trick works nicely, I marked the only "answer" as correct, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can force the path to be local like this:

```
file_exists('file://'. $pathToFile);
```

so if the path has http or something this will fail...